# image dishonors z-index and overlays shadow of pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, image, pseudo-element

I want to cast additional shadows with pseudo-elements ::after and ::before to create sort of a page curl effect. But whenever an `<img>` is involved its src keeps overlaying the shadow. Is that a general limitation or is there a workaround?

```
<ul>
    <li class="imgContainer"><img class="imgFake" /><br><span class="imageTag">some Title</span></li>

    <li class="imgContainer"><img class="imgFake" src="http://wallpaperstock.net/maggie-grace-portrait_wallpapers_14105_1600x1200.jpg"/><br><span class="imageTag">some Title</span></li>

    <li class="imgContainer" style="margin-bottom:50px;"><img class="imgFake" src="http://wallpaperstock.net/maggie-grace-portrait_wallpapers_14105_1600x1200.jpg"/><br><span class="imageTag" style="top:auto; bottom:27px;">some Title</span></li>
</ul>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BpgXC/7/

Comment: Could you please add 4th Image that you expected (Design it in photoshop)

Comment: the jsfiddle currently only looks about right on webkit browsers, but you will get the idea with mozilla.

Comment: @Chandrakant: updated jsfiddle with mockup of intended outcome: http://jsfiddle.net/BpgXC/7/

Comment: Got it, You can set Z-Index to .imgFake, for exp z-index: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/BpgXC/12/

I've changed `img.imgFake` z-index:

```
img.imgFake {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: rgba(135,195,235,.5);
    padding: 5px;
    font: 12px/12px sans-serif;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: sometimes life can be that easy. ^^